# Entity Framework Long Timeout on Queries from Azure PostgresSQL DB

Tags: c#, postgresql, azure, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am having an issue with excessivly long timeouts with calls to an Azure PostgresSQL server.  On rare occasions, the call to the database will take approximately 15 minutes before timing out.  From what we can tell looking at the Azure Portal, the query is not actually even starting.  Here is an example of one of the queries:

```
System system = await (from r in _posSystemManagerContext.System
                       where r.StoreNumber == storeNumber
                          && r.MacAddress.ToLower() == macAddress.ToLower()
                       select r).SingleOrDefaultAsync();
```

This query happens all the time, and typically completes in less than 100ms.  And other queries from other services are all happening at this time too with no issues.  But this one (and a few others) will randomly get an error like this:

```
Failed executing DbCommand (944,756ms) [Parameters=[@__storeNumber_0='?' (DbType = Int32), @__ToLower_1='?'], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30'] SELECT r."StoreNumber", r."MacAddress", r."AddedBy", r."DateAdded", r."DateLastModified", r."LastAccess", r."LastModifiedBy", r."SystemNumber", r."State" FROM "System" AS r WHERE (r."StoreNumber" = @__storeNumber_0) AND (LOWER(r."MacAddress") = @__ToLower_1) LIMIT 2
```

```
An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type 'PosSystemManager.Data.Contexts.PosSystemManagerContext'.
System.InvalidOperationException: An exception has been raised that is likely due to a transient failure. --->
Npgsql.NpgsqlException (0x80004005): Exception while reading from stream --->
System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: Connection timed out. --->
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (110): Connection timed out
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.GetResult(Int16 token)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.<FillBufferAsync>g__InternalFillBufferAsync|215_0[TReadAdapter](TReadAdapter adap, ValueTask`1 task, Int32 min, Int32 initial)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ReadAsyncInternal[TReadAdapter](TReadAdapter adapter, Memory`1 buffer)
at Npgsql.NpgsqlReadBuffer.<>c__DisplayClass34_0.<<Ensure>g__EnsureLong|0>d.MoveNext()
at Npgsql.NpgsqlReadBuffer.<>c__DisplayClass34_0.<<Ensure>g__EnsureLong|0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.<>c__DisplayClass160_0.<<DoReadMessage>g__ReadMessageLong|0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.<>c__DisplayClass160_0.<<DoReadMessage>g__ReadMessageLong|0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult(Boolean async, Boolean isConsuming)
at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync(CommandBehavior behavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(DbContext _, Boolean result, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
```

Our connection string simply has the host, port, user, password, Ssl Mode (Require) and Maximum Pool Size (10).

The application is .NET Core 3.1, with Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL version 3.1.4.  The database is an 8 vCore General Purpose Azure Database for PostgresSQL running version 11.12.

Any idea why this would hang for 15 minutes when the default connection timeout is 15 seconds and the default command timeout is 30 seconds?  Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: As the exception indicates, the cause is some `transient error`, check this common connection issues [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/howto-troubleshoot-common-connection-issues), and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/concepts-connectivity). Check your PGsql server parameters[auto vacuum settings etc], something else may be going on -if there are other app connecting to your DB, the query you refer may not be the only cause!

Comment: Can you try to remove ToLower calls, which discards index usage? Anyway, always check execution plan. Maybe you need additional indexes

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran - I'm not concerned with the fact that there was a transient error.  My concern is how long it took to fail.  The call gets hung for approximately 15 minutes.  Implementing a retry is fine but not when the first call takes 15 minutes before it fails.  In the above example we are not using a cancellation token, but in others we are, which cancel after 30 seconds.  Even with the timeouts from the connection string and the cancellation token, the call still hung for 15 minutes.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv - performance is not really a concern here.  We are talking about a small table with less than 200 rows.  There is no way bad query performance should cause it to take 15 minutes in this scenario.

Comment: Maybe this table under high modification load and Trasaction locks table?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv - looking through the Azure Portal, we are not seeing any locks or long running queries.  It's almost as if the query is never making it to the database.  At this point we are going to try upgrading to .NET 6 (which we planned to do anyway).  According to the release notes for the npgsql packages when upgrading to 5, there were improvements made in handling of cancellations via a token or command timeout, so maybe that will fix our issue.

Comment: What does the database log file say?

Comment: It is also can be DNS, NLB problem.

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading the applications to .NET 6 and Npgsql 6.0.4, all timeouts (and the reason for the timeouts is a whole different problem) are now only taking 30 seconds as expected.